# Use optional argument before options on command line in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line-arguments, getopts

I have a script `myscript` that should do the following:

1. Run on its own: `myscript`
2. Run with an argument: `myscript myarg`
3. Run with options: `myscript -a 1 -b 2 -c 3 ...`
4. Run with an argument and options: `myscript myarg -a 1 -b 2 -c 3 ...`

I cannot get 4. to work, it seems, that using an argument in front of the options (which I take from `getopts`), interferes with the way how `getopts` handles everything.

The code I'm using is basically like this:

```
while getopts "a:b:c:" opt; do
   case ${opt} in
      a)
         var_a=$OPTARG
         ;;
      ... more options here
   esac
done

if [ ! -z "$1" ] && [[ ! "$1" =~ ^- ]]; then
      ... do stuff with first argument - if it's there and it's not just an option
fi
```

If there is a simple solution to this problem, I'd be very thankful!

Comment: Did you think to use shift to get rid of the first argument?

Comment: This is indeed super simple, thanks! I guess the question can be closed, do you want to post it as an answer? Or should I write an answer? One potential downside of the solution: the `if [condition] then ... shift ... fi` has to be used before `getopts` is called, which might be an issue (but not in my case).

Comment: Unless you want to support `myscript -a 1 myarg -b 2 -c 3`, there will be no issue with running `if [[ $1 == myarg ]]; then shift; ...; fi` before your `getopts` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shift` in the last `if` of the script (the general idea is already there, as you write "do stuff with first argument - if it's there and it's not just an option").